# How can I deduce a lower hemisphere's boundary's orientation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Source: Stewart. [*Calculus: Early Transcendentals* (6 edn 2007)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0495011665). p. 1098. §16.8, Exercise #19.

Despite reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262557/determining-correct-orientation-for-stoke), I don't understand how to deduce the red sentence beneath.

> $\text{19}.$ If $S$ is a sphere and $\mathbf{F}$ satisfies the hypotheses of Stokes' Theorem, show that $\iint_S \text{curl} \, \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S} = 0 $.
>
> **Author's Solution:**
> Assume $S$ is centered at the origin with radius $a$. Let $U$ and $L$ be the upper and lower hemispheres, respectively, of $S.$ Then by Stokes' Theorem: $\iint_S (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot d\mathbf{S} = \iint_U (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot d\mathbf{U} + \iint_L (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot d\mathbf{L} = \oint_{\partial U} \! \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r} + \oint_{\partial L} \! \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}  $
> But ${\partial U}$ is $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$ oriented counterclockwise  and $\color{red}{{\partial L} \text{ is the same circle oriented clockwise}}$. (Rest of solution omitted)

**Criterion A for Orientation of Boundary Curve (from Stewart p. 1093):**

> If you walk in the positive direction around $\partial S$ and your head points in the direction of $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$, then the surface will always be on your left.

**Criterion B (from *Thomas' Calculus*, 2009 12 edn, p 963):**

> If the thumb of a right hand points along $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$, then the fingers curl in the direction of $\partial S$.

I know that the orientation of $S$ determines the positive orientation of $\partial S$. Also, the outward unit normals determine any closed surface's positive orientation . Here, the outward unit normals have $z$-component $< 0$ which yields the person in red.

[image]

$\color{purple}{\text{By Criterion A, the red person's head is pointing downwards (in the $-z$ direction)}}.$

$\color{purple}{\text{The purple direction is compulsory for the surface to be on that person's left.}}$

By Criterion B, my thumb must point in the $-z$ direction. So my fingers curl in the orange direction.

Why's there a discrepancy between Criteria A and B? Where's the mistake?

---

$\Large{\text{Supplementary to Prof Shifrin's Answer:}}$

Here's my interpretation: The red person must travel in the purple direction, for the surface to be on her left. Then the purple direction is counterclockwise when viewed from above the $xy$-plane, BUT when viewed from below (as the red person is doing), the purple direction is CLOCKwise.

I had to draw a clock in my updated picture to spot this. Without this clock, I still don't understand why the purple direction can be both clockwise and counterclockwise, depending on from where I look at ahe $xy$-plane. Is there a more intuitive or natural explanation, without drawing clocks?

---

$\Large{\text{2nd Supplementary to Prof Shifrin's Answer:}}$

I still don't understand how to spot that reflections across the $xy$-plane reserve orientation (but preserve direction), without looking at a sheet of paper from above and below.

$\Large{1.}$ Why did you choose the basis {$j, -i, k$}, instead of the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

$\Large{2.}$ Doesn't $-i := (-1,0,0)$ imply that the tip of the vector, lying on the $x$-axis, point towards $-\infty.$ How does it "still point inward"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrong about criterion A. (Fantastic artwork, BTW.) For the lower hemisphere (think disk with downward-pointing normal) to be on your left, you must walk clockwise.

Comment: The terminology is confusing, admittedly. When we say the red person faces and walks clockwise, we mean that from *our* frame of reference, looking from above, not from his own frame of reference. This isn't surprising: If I look *down* on the $xy$-plane I must rotate counterclockwise to get from the $x$-axis to the $y$-axis; but if I look *up* (i.e., from underneath) I must rotate clockwise. To convince yourself, draw the axes on a piece of paper and look from both sides. ... By the way, j'adore votre nom :P

Comment: Professeur, merci beaucoup pour votre réponse et votre reconnaissance de mon nom. After drawing the axes on a piece of paper and looking at it from below, I saw that I must rotate clockwise to get from the $x$-axis to $y$-axis. However, I'm wondering if I could've understood this withOUT looking at a sheet of paper from below? Is there a more abstract or clever way to perceive this change from counterclockwise to clockwise? How can I understand this while looking at the sheet of paper from above?

Comment: M LaPrevoyance, the key thing is that *reflection* across the $xy$-plane is orientation-reversing. This reflection turns your up-standing (:)) red person upside down but does not change the direction he is pointing along the curve. Say he is at the point $(1,0,0)$, so $\vec j$ is the counterclockwise-pointing tangent to the circle. Reflection sends the basis $\vec j, -\vec i,\vec k$ to the basis $\vec j, -\vec i, -\vec k$. For $-\vec k$ to be the normal vector to our downward-pointing disk, since $-\vec i$ still points inward, we must change the sign and make $-\vec j$ our tangent vector.

Comment: Professeur, I thank you deeply for your multiple answers. I apologise for this delay, but even after a few weeks, I'm still stuck. Could you please look at my 3 second supplementary questions in my original post?

Comment: I'm at the point $(1,0,0)$. The vector $\vec j$ points tangent to the circle (the direction I'm walking), the vector $-\vec i$ points *inward* into the disk (think of flattening out the hemisphere), and the vector $\vec k$ points in the direction of my head. Note that everything is happening as I walk around the circle and I'm *at* the point $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: You keep forgetting that you're standing *at* the point $(1,0,0)$. Put your tails of your vectors at the point. Then $(1,0,0)$ is the outward-pointing normal and its negative is the inward-pointing normal.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I now understand that $-i$ points inward into the disk. We want $-k$ to be the normal vector to the downward-pointing disk. However, why do we need $-j$ as our NEW tangent vector? Also, for the upper hemisphere, why pick {$j, -i, k$} as the basis, and not the standard {$i, j, k$}?

Comment: See my response two above. First vector — tangent vector; second — pointing into the surface; third — outward normal to the surface. This must make a right-handed system. If the second two vectors are $-\vec i$ and $-\vec k$, the first must be $-\vec j$ if we are to have a right-handed system. (J'arrive en France à la fin de juillet :))

Comment: Thanks so much. I've drawn a picture in a separate Answer below for your latest response. Is it 100% right? Unfortunately, I still can't fathom: For the upper hemisphere, why pick {$j, -i, k$} as the basis, and not the standard {$i, j, k$}?

Comment: Think about how you apply the right-hand rule: You point your fingers along the curve [first vector], curl them into the surface [second vector], and then your thumb points in the direction of the outward normal [third vector].

Comment: After rumination, I understand that the RH rule applied for Criterion B would result in my thumb signifying $\mathbf{\hat{k}} = \text{ third vector }$. However, I can't grasp what would lead me to "point fingers along the curve" to obtain $\mathbf{\hat{j}}$ [first vector] and to "curl them into the surface" to obtain $-\mathbf{\hat{i}}$ [second vector]?

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand orientation on this intuitive level work with the following paradigm: Assume that the $(x,y)$-plane $z=0$  of $(x,y,z)$-space is oriented "upwards", in other words: that $n=(0,0,1)$ is the "positive" normal, and consider the unit disk $D$ in the $(x,y)$-plane with its boundary $\partial D$. Then the positive orientation of $\partial D$ is for all of us the counterclockwise orientation, as seen from the tip of $n$, or from high up on the $z$-axis.

This is in accordance with your Criterion A: A man walking along $\partial D$ with his head in direction $n$, i.e., upright on the $(x,y)$-plane,  has $D$ to his left.

It is also in accordance with your Criterion B: Position your right hand at $(1,0)\in\partial D$, the thumb in direction $n$. Then the fingers will curl around $\partial D$ in the counterclockwise direction, as seen from above.

Now to your lower hemisphere: A (red) man walking along $\partial L$ upright on the sphere, i.e., with the length of his body in the plane $z=0$, will have $L$ to his left when he walks *clockwise*, as seen by a spectator high up on the $z$-axis. The same spectator will perceive the other man walking along $\partial U$ having $U$ to his left as walking in the *counterclockwise* direction.

By the way: It is not necessary to cut up the sphere. It is enough to note that $\partial S^2$ for a full sphere $S^2$ is $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You wrote: "Now to your lower hemisphere... as seen by a spectator $\color{red}{\text{high up.}}$" Since the red person's point of view is from the tip of the vector $(0, 0, -1)$, shouldn't this end with "...as seen by a spectator $\color{limegreen}{\text{from below}}$"?

Comment: @LaPrevoyance: See my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. In my Second Answer to this question (the bottom of this Question thread), I've drawn a picture for your second last paragraph. Does it match your meaning 100%?

Answer (score 0):

With many thanks to Profs Schrin and Blatter's response, I had an epiphany on how to comprehend/intuit, without looking at a sheet of paper from above and below, that when viewed from below, the purple direction is clockwise. The key picture is:

[image]

To do so, I followed Prof Blatter's advice just to look at the unit disk. The revealing moment came after drawing the clock on the unit disk. I saw that when viewed from above (the $xy$-plane), $\color{yellowgreen}?$ = 3 so purple = counterclockwise. On the other hand, when viewed from below, so when I look at the $xy$-plane from the tip of $(0, 0, -1)$ or from the point of view of the red person, $\color{yellowgreen}?$ = 9 so purple = clockwise.

The short answer is that because, for example,  $ \color{yellowgreen}{? =} \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
      \color{yellowgreen}3&\color{yellowgreen}{,\text{when viewed from above = tip of } (0,0,1)} \\
      \color{yellowgreen}9&\color{yellowgreen}{,\text{when viewed from below = tip of } (0,0,-1)}
    \end{array}
  \right. $

therefore when viewed from the other side of the $xy$-plane, a clock changes its order : 1 $\rightarrow$ 11, 2 $\rightarrow$ 10, 3 $\rightarrow$ 9, 4 $\rightarrow$ 8, 5 $\rightarrow$ 7 while 12 and 6 o'clocks remain the same. This explains why reflections across the $xy$-plane reverse orientation.

Answer (score 0):

My Picture for Prof Blatter's Second Last Paragraph:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My Picture for Prof Shifrin's Answer on June 29th 2013: Green is for $\pm\mathbf{\hat{j}}$, red for $-\mathbf{\hat{i}}$, purple for $\pm\mathbf{\hat{k}}$. All hands are right hands herein.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My Picture for Prof Shifrin's Answer on June 30th 2013. As before, green is for $\pm\mathbf{\hat{j}}$, red for $-\mathbf{\hat{i}}$, purple for $\pm\mathbf{\hat{k}}$.

[image]